# CSS: Box positioning and responsiveness

Tags: css, alignment, responsive-design

On several of my pages (currently the site is under development), some weather info will be shown: [LINK](http://www.golfanatics.de/J3/index.php/component/content/article/182-golfhotels/europa/spanien/23-best-western-hotel-subur-maritim.html)
CSS Problem Description: under the headline WETTER you can see 4 boxes. One is displaying weather from today (HEUTE) and three boxes underneath display the weather from the next days. As you can see, the 3 small boxes are not exactly adding up to 100% framewidth. Also, the uppor wide box is of a slight different width.

--> how is is possible to reach the following?
a) the 3 boxes together to add up to the exact same width as the wide box above WHEN USING A WEBBROWSER / IPAD in landscape view, and AT THE SAME TIME
b) to have FOUR boxes underneath of each other (with 100% pagewidth) when browsing the page with an iPhone/Android. Looking forward to any hints you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have understood what you wanted.

I have made a rough demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/Txjh5/

Used an overall container to simulate your framewidth - this has a max-width.
The boxes are at a percentage to match the top box but using margins I have created gaps between the boxes.

```
.last {margin-right: 0;}
```

Removes the margin for the last box.

A media query is used for the smaaller screen size to force each box to 100% width.

Sorry if I have misunderstood the question, but have a look at the demo as that explains things better than I can!

Comment: Would love to do that - since I am a rookie here, how can I do that?

Comment: Dear Stuart, I reopened this thread, still one problem persists: while in Browsers it looks great, on iPhone portrait view (my core target for the mobile devices) the boxes are cut at the right edge. I have already played around with the width% in the @media CSS element, but do not get it working fully:

Comment: @media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .wetter .wetterheute-feld, .wetter .wetter-feld{
        margin: 2px;
        width: 49%;
    } 
}

Comment: Try removing the `min-width:` & `max-width`'s of `.wetter`

Comment: Stuart: A BIG THANKS - that was it. Best regards and greetings from Germany! Ralph